# SharedPreference doesn't work in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I use this code to save String value in SharedPreference , But returns empty String! I tried very hard and spend long time, But I can't understand why?

```
sp=getSharedPreferences("sp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    sp.edit().putString("a","ali");
                    sp.edit().commit();

                    Log.i("sp","z"+sp.getString("a","");
                }
            });
```

Comment: use this:editor = sp.edit();

Comment: Worked, I used Editor aa=sp.edit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("sp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor aa = sp.edit();
Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("myStrings", new HashSet<String>());

// Add the new value.
myStrings.add("Another string");

// Save the list.
aa.putStringSet("myStrings", myStrings);
aa.commit();
```